# \newcolumntype with automatic & insertion

Tags: tables

In brief: I want to define a new tabular column type using `\newcolumntype` from the `array` package which is designed to be not occuring as the last column in `tabular` environment but adds an automatic `&` as tab alignment (separating two cells as usual).

A special case could be a row numbering type `N` in the first column of a table (see definition in the MWE below), such that

```
\begin{tabular}{Nrr}
  Line & One \tabularnewline
  Line & Two \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

is the same as typing `&` explicitly (using `N` type with does not automatically add `&`, of course)

```
\begin{tabular}{Nrr}
  & Line & One \tabularnewline
  & Line & Two \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

*Please note that the numbering is just an example. The question is of a more general nature, for 'any' user defined column type*

I failed since LaTeX complains about

```
! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.
<to be read again> 
                   &
l.15 \begin{tabular}{Nrr}
```

I guess it's some `\catcode` issue, but I can't figure out how to change it.

Is this automated `&` insertion possible at all?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcounter{tabline}

%\newcolumntype{N}{>{\stepcounter{tabline}\thetabline &\arraybackslash}r} % does not work

\xpretocmd{\tabular}{\setcounter{tabline}{0}}{}{} % Lazy, I know 

\newcolumntype{N}{>{\stepcounter{tabline}\thetabline \arraybackslash}r}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{Nrr}
  Line & One \tabularnewline
  Line & Two \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{Nrr}
  & Line & One \tabularnewline
  & Line & Two \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

I omitted a screenshot since it's quite clear how the (primitive) table would look like (and the real case is of course more complicated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually possible but massively fragile and not normally required, for example row numbering can be done as:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{tabline}

\xpretocmd{\tabular}{\setcounter{tabline}{0}}{}{} % Lazy, I know 

\newcolumntype{N}{!{\refstepcounter{tabline}\thetabline}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{Nrr}
  Line & One \tabularnewline
  Line & Two \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{Nrr}
   Line & One \tabularnewline
   Line & Two \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

if you're feeling brave, an alternative

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blkarray}

\newcounter{tabline}


\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\begin{blockarray}{lrr}
col1&col2&col3\\
\begin{block}{\BAmulticolumn{2}{>{\refstepcounter{tabline}\thetabline\hfill}r}r}
   Line & One \\
   Line & Two \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a nice way, but as I wrote, the numbering is just one possibility (actually, I am a lazy guy and wanted to prevent typing `&` a lot ;-))

Comment: That's cheating ;-). You are not putting the numbers in a column but between them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It must be a _column_, `N` is defined with `\newcolumntype` :-)

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence yes but numbering is just an example here you can add any text, if necessary in a `\makebox[3cm]{...}` to force the width. but I added a blkarray version

Answer (score 4):

I would set the row number as part of the column separation, using something like:

```
\newcolumntype{N}{@{\refstepcounter{tabline}\thetabline\hspace{\tabcolsep}}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,xpatch}
\newcounter{tabline}

\xpretocmd{\tabular}{\setcounter{tabline}{0}}{}{} % Lazy, I know 

\newcolumntype{N}{@{\refstepcounter{tabline}\thetabline\hspace{\tabcolsep}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{Nrr}
  Line & One \tabularnewline
  Line & Two \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|N|r|r|}
  Line & One \tabularnewline
  Line & Two \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps more enhancements are needed if you want to insert appropriate spacing on the left. However, those are additional options one can insert into the `N` column type.